# How to avoid having current directory in Python's sys.path while keeping user site packages?

Tags: python, command-line

The users can execute my Python app in directories containing their own Python scripts. If any of these scripts has name which clashes with a library module used by my program (or even clashes with the name of my module), everything breaks with an unhelpful error message.

I know that Python (since 3.4) has `-I` switch, which makes import machinery ignore current directory (ie. `""` won't be added to `sys.path`). This would almost solve my problem, but it has the side effect of also ignoring user site packages.

I know I can tweak `sys.path` after my program has loaded, but it won't help if the user (by accident) shadows the main module of my program.

Can I somehow make Python ignore current directory but give me user site packages at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can re-enable the user site paths, by calling `site.addusersitepackages(None)` (the `None` simply means: check existing `sys.path` definitions to avoid adding duplicate paths):

```
import site
import sys

if sys.flags.no_user_site and sys.prefix == sys.base_prefix:
    # python -s or python -I has disabled user sites, and this is not a virtualenv
    site.ENABLE_USER_SITE = True
    site.addusersitepackages(None)
```

Quick demo:

```
>>> import site, sys, os.path
>>> user_site = os.path.expanduser(f"~/.local/lib/python{sys.version_info.major}.{sys.version_info.minor}/site-packages")
>>> user_site in sys.path
False
>>> sys.flags.no_user_site
1
>>> site.ENABLE_USER_SITE = True
>>> site.addusersitepackages(None)
>>> user_site in sys.path
True
```

While `site.addusersitepackages()` *is* undocumented, it is a key component of `site.main()` and is [also quite simple](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/site.py#L305-L317). If you feel you can’t rely on its continued existence, reimplement it like this:

```
import os.path
import site

def addusersitepackages():
    user_site = site.getusersitepackages()

    if site.ENABLE_USER_SITE and os.path.isdir(user_site):
        site.addsitedir(user_site)
```

This version omits the `known_paths` argument entirely, and only uses documented `site` attributes and functions: [`site.getusersitepackages()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html#site.getusersitepackages), [`site.ENABLE_USER_SITE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html#site.ENABLE_USER_SITE) and [`site.addsitedir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html#site.addsitedir).

Or, fold the above into the code to enable the user site directory, wrapped as a function:

```
import os.path
import site
import sys

def ensure_usersitepackages():
    if sys.flags.no_user_site and sys.prefix == sys.base_prefix:
        # if python -s or python -I has disabled user sites, and this 
        # is not a virtualenv, explicitly enable user sites anyway.
        site.ENABLE_USER_SITE = True
        user_site = site.getusersitepackages()
        if os.path.isdir(user_site):
            site.addsitedir(user_site)
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you know why `addusersitepackages` isn't mentioned in `site`'s API docs? It doesn't look like a private function. Is it quaranteed to exist in all installations of CPython (let's say 3.9 and later)?

Comment: @Aivar: it's an internal `site` function, and is not documented because no-one thought it would be needed to be documented, at a guess. I can't tell you if it is guaranteed to exist in later Python versions because I don't have a crystal ball, but it exists in all Python 3.x releases so far (including 3.10a6).

Comment: @Aivar I added an inline implementation for `addusersitepackages()` in case you’re still concerned about its long-term viability.